# Export data from a web table to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm creating a python script that allows me to automate one of my repetitive tasks.

I create automatic expert advisors to invest in the financial markets to which I have to periodically check the results and bring them to an excel, this obviously allows a lot of human error.

I would like to automate the export of the results, and I was able to make the script log into my online account, once I got to the table I found a way to export all the results, the problem is that I cannot report them again in the form of a table ...

If I try to write them on an excel, it writes them all to me in one column. A tidy way would be the dictionary, but I don't know how to go about that from the web table.
I am attaching my code, the site in question is https://www.fxblue.com/

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Variabili 
Username = ''
Password = ''
TableValue = []

# Link sito web da cui iniziare scraping
FxBlueLink = 'https://www.fxblue.com/live/'

# Installo i driver google con il modulo webdriver_manager.chrome
ChromeDriver = ChromeDriverManager().install()

# Avvio il browser
Browser = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriver))

# Ingrandisco a tutto schermo chrome
Browser.maximize_window()

# Vado al link 
Browser.get(FxBlueLink)

# Trovo input Username e Password
Browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
"/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/input").send_keys(Username)

Browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
"/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input").send_keys(Password)

sleep(2)

# Click pulsante di Login
Browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
"/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input").click()

sleep(2)

# Vado sulle statistiche
Browser.get("https://www.fxblue.com/users/rdrtrader")

sleep(2)

# Vado su Analisi
Browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
"/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").click()

sleep(2)

# Vado su Menu Simbolo e scelgo magic number
Browser.find_element(By.ID, "ext-gen24").click()

sleep(2)

Browser.find_element(By.ID, "ext-gen71").click()

sleep(2)

# Scraping tabella

Table =  Browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "x-grid3-body").text

TableValue = Table

print(TableValue)   

sleep(1)
    
input()
```

Comment: As the website is behind a login, can you post **full** HTML of the page containing the table with results you're looking for?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/s5da75osvrfm27y/FX+Blue+-+Statement+.html/file

Thanks!

Comment: I use mediafire because full html it's too long for post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at that long html file. Supposing you are able to access it with Selenium, all you have to do is:

```
import pandas as pd
import time as t
[... rest of imports, and code to get to that page]

t.sleep(5) ## this is just for good measure, you could in theory  skip it
dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
for df in dfs:
print(df)
```

Pandas recognizes 36 tables in the html you provided. Locate the tables you need, and then do df.to_csv('relevant_name.csv') for each of them. Or filter them based on keywords/content.

Relevant documentation for pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! but i have another problem, practically to get to the table I need there are several steps as you can see from my code, and in those steps the url is always the same, only the table changes. For this reason, by inserting the url in pd.read_html I do not go to fetch the necessary table but the one with the initial data

Comment: @RHale I'm not sure I understand what you are saying: aren't you using selenium to open the page? You don't insert any url in `pd.read_html(...)`, you insert the `browser.page_source` there.

Comment: I managed to solve it thanks to you